# Is it possible to reference a resource within a resource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I know how I can declare a resource. A `Color` for example

```
<Color x:Key="MyColorResource">#ffffff</Color>
```

But what if I want to use another resource within my resource. Something like this

```
<Color x:Key="Theme.Highlight">#ffffff</Color>
<Color x:Key="MyColorResource">{StaticResource Theme.Highlight}</Color>
```

Would this be possible?

Comment: Yes, have you tried actually doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can not directly reference** inside an element.

You **can reference** one resource inside another **resources property**.

```
<Color x:Key="MyColorResource">#ffffff</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrushResource" Color="{StaticResource MyColorResource}" />
```

**Note**: your references should be compatible types.